# Не работает js в IE 11, в остальных браузерах - ок

Tags: javascript, jquery

Мой первый сайт partnernkt.ru, сильно не пинайте. 
На странице https://partnernkt.ru/cable_protector.html не работает сортировка по диаметру трубы, и именно только в IE11.
Отчаялась найти решение. ПОМОГИТЕ!!

jquery-3.4.1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#filter_48').on('click', ()=> {
    $('.product_item').addClass('hide_diametr');
    $('.d_48').removeClass('hide_diametr');
});
$('#filter_60').on('click', ()=> {
    $('.product_item').addClass('hide_diametr');
    $('.d_60').removeClass('hide_diametr');
});
$('#filter_73').on('click', ()=> {
    $('.product_item').addClass('hide_diametr');
    $('.d_73').removeClass('hide_diametr');
});
$('#filter_89').on('click', ()=> {
    $('.product_item').addClass('hide_diametr');
    $('.d_89').removeClass('hide_diametr');
    $('#filter_89').addClass('red');
});
$('#filter_102').on('click', ()=> {
    $('.product_item').addClass('hide_diametr');
    $('.d_102').removeClass('hide_diametr');
});
$('#filter_114').on('click', ()=> {
    $('.product_item').addClass('hide_diametr');
    $('.d_114').removeClass('hide_diametr');
});
$('#filter_127').on('click', ()=> {
  $('.product_item').addClass('hide_diametr');
    $('.d_127').removeClass('hide_diametr');
});
$('#filter_139').on('click', ()=> {
    $('.product_item').addClass('hide_diametr');
    $('.d_139').removeClass('hide_diametr');
});
$('#filter_168').on('click', ()=> {
  $('.product_item').addClass('hide_diametr');
    $('.d_168').removeClass('hide_diametr');
});
$('#filter_178').on('click', ()=> {
  $('.product_item').addClass('hide_diametr');
    $('.d_178').removeClass('hide_diametr');
});
$('#filter_wide').on('click', ()=> {
    $('.product_item').addClass('hide_wide');
    $('.wide').removeClass('hide_wide');
});
$('#filter_diametr_all').on('click', ()=> {
    $('.product_item').removeClass('hide_diametr');
    $('.product_item').removeClass('hide_wide');
    $('#filter_48 input').removeProp('checked');
    $('#filter_60 input').removeProp('checked');
    $('#filter_73 input').removeProp('checked');
    $('#filter_89 input').removeProp('checked');
    $('#filter_102 input').removeProp('checked');
    $('#filter_114 input').removeProp('checked');
  $('#filter_127 input').removeProp('checked');
    $('#filter_139 input').removeProp('checked');
  $('#filter_168 input').removeProp('checked');
  $('#filter_178 input').removeProp('checked');
});

</script>
```

Comment: Попробуйте заменить вызов on('click... на вызов click( () => ...

Comment: СПАСИБО БОЛЬШОЕ

Answer (score 2):

У вас ie выдает ошибку на .on('click', ()=>
Замените на

```
    $('#filter_stamped_clamp').on('click', function() {
//действие
});
```

Для всех подобных вызовов

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions - "Browser Compatibility"